# How to make a Mac installer from a jar file?

Tags: java

How to make a Mac installer from a jar file?

Answer (score 0):

[Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) can install Java apps. to Windows, *nix **and** Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't actually *need* an native installer, if a runnable jar file is enough. I know of a product that uses this approach: Day [CRX](http://www.day.com/day/en/products/crx.html) and [CQ](http://www.day.com/day/en/products/web_content_management.html). Disclaimer: I work for Day. If you are interested, you might want to try it out (not because of the product maybe, but because of the way it is run). After you start it (double click), it does unpack files, but I wouldn't call it 'installer' - it just happens to unpack the files the first time it is run.